# Detecting enter key pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Are there any ways available in jquery to detect whether <kbd>Enter</kbd> key has pressed?

I know that we can use keycodes/charset to identify the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press, but I do not need to hard code an integer value in my js script as it will become a magical number. I need to know whether there are any other possible ways to detect <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press, which is something like `e.shiftKey` for detecting shift key press using event object.

Thanks.

Comment: You can simply declare your own variable that stores the number 13 to avoid having a magic number peppered through your code

Comment: you can always remove the magic from the magic numbers by naming them yourself :) `var enterKey = 13;` or similar

Comment: I think there is no way except to hardcode the value as `13`

Comment: @karthik If you declare the var yourself (ie ENTERKEY=13), you need only set it in one place, instead of having lots of 13s throughout your code. It makes it easier to search the code for keyhandlers, and if the international standards committee revokes ASCII as a standard you can just update a single variable declaration ;).

Comment: @MattCoubrough Yeah, that will be good for maintenance too ;)

Comment: @karthik: who knows, the keycodes might change ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you want to detect the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key being pressed without hardcoding a `13` for the keycode.

Now, I could suggest using `6.5*2` as the keycode, then, but that'd be silly.

The real answer is that there is no built-in constant for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, like the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key has.

The reason <kbd>Shift</kbd> has it, is because that key is often pressed in combination with other keys. You can't detect a <kbd>Shift</kbd> `keyDown` event when pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, for example, because the event for the modifier has passed already when you're handling the `keyDown` event for the <kbd>A</kbd>.

Frankly, your only *real* option would be to hardcode a application-wide constant that says something along the lines of:

```
window.keyCodes = {
    Enter: 13,
    SomeKey: 99
}
```

Then you can check against it like this:

```
if(e.keyCode === keyCodes.Enter)
```

Or, it may be possible to write a function that compares the character of the entered key with a string that contains only a return, but then you'd just be hardcoding a return, any way.

Comment: Thanks. If it is so, then it seems like I do not have any other options other than using keycode right?

Answer (score 1):

The keycode for the enter key is : 13

```
if(e.keyCode == 13)
  //do something...
```

Comment: @R. Canser Yanbakan:

Thanks. 

But as I have mentioned in the description, I do not want use this method. I need to know whether there are any other solutions available to detect enter key press without using keycode. 

Something like e.shiftKey for detecting shift key.

Comment: @zulox the shift key is a modifier key. It is only meaningful if pressed in combination with a non-modifier key. That's why shift gets a separate field (so you could detect shift + enter). But the non-modifier key that was pressed has always been addressed by its keycode because it's always the same field that contains the pressed keyvalue. The enter button is one of those non-modifier keys.

Comment: @Flater: Thanks and if so then I have no other options other than going for keycode right :)

Comment: @zulox: Yes. Any other solution just adds more weight to the problem. But like I said, 99% of the magic of magic numbers disappears if you use understandable variable names like `var enterKeyCode = 13;` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

This is the immediate way that people detect this particular event, but there are other ways to identify the number 13.

```
var DOM_VK_RETURN = 13;

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if(code == DOM_VK_RETURN) {
    console.log("Enter key pressed");
  }
});
```

However, if you do not want to use an integer to detect the key, we could use hexadecimal.

http://jsfiddle.net/hk2eL/3/

Comment: @MattCoubrough: You may have copied Bharadwaj's comment, but you forgot the formatting :)

Comment: @Flater Code has been updated so my comment has been removed. It does astound me how quickly people manage to give an answer that fails to address the actual question at hand

Comment: But should actually need to explain `Why` this way, `Why Not` other way?

Comment: _"However, if you do not want to use an integer to detect the key, we could use hexadecimal."_ No... Just, no. Sure, it'll work, but you're just over-complicating things for the sake of not using `13` in the code. And guess what the hex value for the [Pause/Break] key is? `13`! (Decimal: 19)